# Remove particular UTF-8 character from string with PHP

Tags: php, replace

I get some strings from remote API and someone contains char `ð` (I couldn't get rid of or replace it)

I tried

```
$str = str_replace("ð", "", $str); 

$str = strtr($str,'ð','');
```

There is no effect

Comment: Is your php file encoded as utf-8? And served as utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = iconv( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $str);
or
$str = iconv( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $str);
```

hope this will work.
use iconv() instead of str_replace

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing its html entity, like:

```
str_replace("&eth;","",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php file is not encoded in UTF-8 according to me. Specify it using the headers. Use the code below

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str="hð";
$str = strtr($str,'ð','');
echo $str; // print h
```

or

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        $str="hð";
    $str = str_replace("ð", "", $str); 
echo $str; // prints h
```

Hope this helps you